# sed awk replace lines with a pattern match

Tags: replace, awk, sed

With awk or sed how could I replace each line after a pattern match? 
the pattern would always start as S:\ and something else, 
I need the entire line from S:\~ to the end to appear on the next lines before a blank line.

I have an input like this:

```
S:\dir1\subfolder1longsubf
abcdefg
1234567
permissions

S:\dir2\verylongsub
some random string
some random string

S:\dir3
some random string
some random string

S:\dir4\sub2\sub3
some random string
some random string
some random string
```

and I need an ouput like this:

```
S:\dir1\subfolder1longsubf
S:\dir1\subfolder1longsubf
S:\dir1\subfolder1longsubf
S:\dir1\subfolder1longsubf

S:\dir2\verylongsub
S:\dir2\verylongsub
S:\dir2\verylongsub

S:\dir3
S:\dir3
S:\dir3

S:\dir4\sub2\sub3
S:\dir4\sub2\sub3
S:\dir4\sub2\sub3
S:\dir4\sub2\sub3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '/^S/ {line=$0} {print NF?line:""}' file
```

This stores the line starting with `S`. Then, it prints either this stored value or an empty line if the line is empty.

#### Test

```
$ awk '/^S/ {line=$0} {print NF?line:""}' file
S:\dir1\subfolder1longsubf
S:\dir1\subfolder1longsubf
S:\dir1\subfolder1longsubf
S:\dir1\subfolder1longsubf

S:\dir2\verylongsub
S:\dir2\verylongsub
S:\dir2\verylongsub

S:\dir3
S:\dir3
S:\dir3

S:\dir4\sub2\sub3
S:\dir4\sub2\sub3
S:\dir4\sub2\sub3
S:\dir4\sub2\sub3
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed  '/^S:/{h};/^[^S]/{g}' file
```

Comment: This presumes that blank lines contains no white space at all. A safer solution would be to leave *empty lines* alone:`sed '/^\s*$/b;/^S:\\/h;//!g' file`